# Why is "living room" two words, yet "bedroom" is one word?

Tags: etymology, orthography

Is there an origin difference or English reason why "living room" is two words, but "bedroom" is only one?

Comment: Open compounds resist solidification when the resulting single orthographic word would lead to a garden-path situation (there are grooms, but no drooms).

Comment: *bedroom, bathroom, storeroom* but *living room, dining room, reading room*.

Comment: Both of them are really one word. The space between _living_ and _room_ is present only in writing; it's an artifact of the history of printing and has nothing to do with the English language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Living room" has been in the language a while; the OED's first quote for it is from 1787. I think it hasn't become a compound word due to "living" ending in "ing". Words that end in "ing" seem to only very rarely form the first part of [closed compound words](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/open-and-closed-compound-words/).

Looking at the OED, there are over a hundred entries listed that end in "ing room" or "ing-room" but none that end in "ingroom". (If you have access to the OED, you can see this by searching for `*ingroom`.) The same thing can be seen if you search for `living*`, to find all the entries that start with "living". There are very few entries that were a single word (none of which were compound words, as far as I saw). Most entries had a space and one had a hyphen ("living-in", which as an adjective is different).